# How to create 3D images from .nii file

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, classification, visualization

What are `.nii` files, and how is data stored in them? I have some of these and I want to know how can I create `3D` image of `MRI` scan from them.

I can load the file in my python script using nibabel. Where to go from here next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common way of processing images in python through numpy arrays. Since you have already loaded your image through nibabel, you need to get the data from the image object and then cast it as a numpy array.

```
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np

# Get nibabel image object
img = nib.load("path/to/image.nii")

# Get data from nibabel image object (returns numpy memmap object)
img_data = img.get_data()

# Convert to numpy ndarray (dtype: uint16)
img_data_arr = np.asarray(img_data)
```

By default this should be a 3D numpy array with a shape of (height,width,image). If you want to access one image you can always use PIL. For example to save the first image of the .nii file:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(img_data_arr_norm[:,:,0], 'L')
img.save("image.jpeg")
```

Comment: **How can I then load the image in another program?**

Comment: Before saving the slices into the image , I looked at them using matplotlib.pyplot and was able to see all the sections of the brain. But when i saved the slices into the image form as specified using PIL. I see blank images in my directory.

Comment: What other program are you talking about? The blank images are probably an issue of the conversion from numpy array to PIL Image. Try saving the image through matplotlib.pyplot.imsave().